# JSwing, how do I make a Jtable render prior to starting another action?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

I've got and action listener for my buttons on a normal Jpanel, when I click the button its supposed to bring up a contact window, and then send each of them a text 1 by 1. It brings up a window and stays blank until after the text messages have been sent out, even though here in my action listener it clearly requires the window to be brought up first.

```
        else if (ae.getActionCommand() == "Initiate Recall") {

        int doneCheck = 0;

        if (doneCheck == 0){
        oh.ViewAllMembers();
        doneCheck = 1;
        }
        if (doneCheck == 1){
        try {

            oh.doRecall();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

Here is my do Recall Method

```
public void doRecall() throws Exception {

    String customMessage = getMessage();
    boolean programOpen = true;

    Member con = new Member();

    Object data[][] = new Object[v.size()][8];

    k = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++) {

        con = (Member) v.elementAt(k);

        data[j][0] = con.getFName();
        data[j][1] = con.getLName();
        data[j][2] = con.getNname();
        data[j][3] = con.getEMail();
        data[j][4] = con.getAddress();
        data[j][5] = con.getPhoneNo();
        data[j][6] = con.getresponse();
        data[j][7] = con.getBday();

        try {
            String myPasscode = "*******";
            String myUsername = "*******";
            String toPhoneNumber = con.getPhoneNo();
            customMessage = customMessage.replaceAll("\\s+", "+");
            System.out.println(customMessage);

            String requestUrl = ("http://cloud.fowiz.com/api/message_http_api.php?username=******&phonenumber=+"
                    + toPhoneNumber + "&message=" + customMessage + "&passcode=******");

            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);

            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            System.out.println(uc.getResponseMessage());
            String reply = uc.getResponseMessage();

            if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
        k++;

    }
    k = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++) {

        con = (Member) v.elementAt(k);

        boolean phoneCheck = false;
        while (phoneCheck != true) {
            mR2 = new MailReader();
            String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
            String mailStoreType = "pop3";
            String username = "*********@gmail.com";// change
                                                        // accordingly
            String password = "*******";// change accordingly
            MailReader.check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
            if (MailReader.searchForPhone(con.getPhoneNo()) == true) {
                System.out.println("IT WORKED");
                phoneCheck = true;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

and here is my view contact method

```
public void ViewAllMembers() {

    newFrame = new JFrame("All Members In The Roster");
    newFrame.setSize(600, 300);
    newFrame.setIconImage(img);

    Member con = new Member();

    String columnNames[] = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Nickname",
            "E Mail Address", "Address", "Phone No.", "response", "B'day" };

    Object data[][] = new Object[v.size()][8];

    for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++) {

        con = (Member) v.elementAt(k);

        data[j][0] = con.getFName();
        data[j][1] = con.getLName();
        data[j][2] = con.getNname();
        data[j][3] = con.getEMail();
        data[j][4] = con.getAddress();
        data[j][5] = con.getPhoneNo();
        data[j][6] = con.getresponse();
        data[j][7] = con.getBday();

        k++;

    }
    k = 0;

    JTable abtable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(abtable);
    abtable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 370));

    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Members Currently In The Recall Roster");
    pane.add(label);

    newFrame.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    newFrame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    newFrame.setLocation(screenWidth / 4, screenHeight / 4);
    newFrame.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

```
    else if (ae.getActionCommand() == "Initiate Recall") {
```

Don't use `==` to compare Strings. Understand that `==` checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if ("bar".equals(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if ("bar".equalsIgnoreCase(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

Next:

```
    int doneCheck = 0;

    if (doneCheck == 0){
    oh.ViewAllMembers();
```

I'm guessing this is a long running bit of code -- you never tell us what this does (??). If so, it's putting your complete Swing GUI to sleep making it unresponsive. perhaps it needs to run on a background thread.

```
    doneCheck = 1;
    }
    if (doneCheck == 1){
    try {
        oh.doRecall();
    }
```

Does `oh.doRecall()` show your JTable? If so, or if not, you're not explaining your code well to us but seem to be assuming that we can understand code and concepts not shown. Reality check: we can't.

---

**Edit**

- Your `doRecall()` code should be called in a background thread, such as with a SwingWorker (Google `Concurrency in Swing`), because it is tying up the Swing event thread, preventing your other code from showing. This is your major problem, and the tutorial will help you learn how to fix it.
- You seem to be showing multiple JFrames, a common Swing newbie mistake that you'll want to fix. If you need to show a dependent window, show a dialog such as a JDialog, or don't show a sub window and swap views with a CardLayout.
- Again, don't use `==` to compare Strings.
- Don't call deprecated methods such as `JFrame#show()`. They're deprecated for a reason, and the Java API will tell you about the alternatives that you should use.

---

Something like....

```
        if ("Initiate Recall".equalsIgnoreCase(ae.getActionCommand())) {
           // viewAllMembers method name should begin with a lower-case letter 
           oh.viewAllMembers();
           SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
              @Override
              protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                 oh.doRecall();
                 return null;
              }

              @Override
              protected void done() {
                 try {
                    get();
                 } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    // do something with any exceptions here
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              }
           };
           worker.execute();
        }
```

Comment: Okay, Ill had some more source code. My last post had complaints that I included too much, so I tried to cut it down. Also, those are ints not strings?

Comment: That tutorial really helped, and your suggested method worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Remixt: glad you're moving forward!